# is there a Method to find the element obscuring the target element when encountering ElementClickInterceptedException?

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to write a selenium script and I want to write a method to handle modals or overlayers obscuring a page or an element. Is there a way to read from the ElementClickInterceptedException the name and the attributes of the element obscuring the target?

I have read the [documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html?overview-summary.html) and there does not seem to be any method to retrieve only this piece of information. The only viable way would seem to be by parsing the error message and retrieving the id of the modal/overlay from there

Comment: Why do you need to deal with obscuring element? In case of `ElementClickInterceptedException` you should wait for elements to become on their final locations and / or scroll the target element or click it with JavaScript click. These are normal approaches to resolve `ElementClickInterceptedException` exception.

Comment: You need that because there could be a modal dialog in front of the element you are trying to click.  It'll be there right at the end of the exception.  Just try/catch the call.

Comment: Clicking the target element with Javascript does not test if the modal window can be closed by a normail user. By sidestepping the modal, you might miss a bug where the modal can not be closed from the modal button. A method that ca programatically detect which element is obscuring the target element, can be used on more than one modal and helps with code reuse

Comment: There should be a repeatable procedure to launch the modal.  If, for some reason, it appears at random, you might consider checking for it's existence using WebDriverEventListeners: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverEventListener.html  (or an implementation like that)

Comment: thank you Prophet and pcalkins but I still don't understand exactly what event in the WebDriverListener class should I be listening to in order to detect if and when a modal window has appeared on the screen. Thank you for clarifying that for me

Comment: When the exception is thrown it will tell you what webelement is getting the click.  (Selenium's exceptions are well designed...)  Check the exception.  You'll be checking for the existence of that element.  Again, you can probably come up with a repeatable procedure, so in that case an eventlistener wouldn't be necessary.